how to select suitable parameters for snic in GEE for crop classification
var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(100);
// Apply image segmentation
var segmentation = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: stackedImage,
  compactness: 5,
  connect`your text`ivity: 8,
  seeds: seeds,
  neighborhoodSize: 286,
  //size: 10,
});

i want to do segmentation on sentinel-1 and sentinel-2 alongwith NDVI fusion compsites but when i select these paraemetrs and perform classification i got 70 accuracy my segments are not according to my data kindly tell me how to select suitable parameters according to my data specification i have 7 classes in survey data.
I tried by tunning different parameters but the accuracy is no more then 70 i am expecting to select such parameters with the help of which accuracy reached upto 90 or more .
